# Render kernels problem

Tags: rendering

I am running a mac pro on osx yosemite dual core xenon with radeon hd5770 graphics and it wont render in gpu compute. says it has a problem with render kernels

Answer (score 2):

Sort Answer: Your card is not suported

OpenCL GPU compute for AMD GPUs is not on the same level of support as Nvidia, there are lots of known issues, limitations, and unsupported features.

**Edit:** As of Blender 2.79 some serious improvements have been made, supported by AMD themselves, OpenCL GPU computing is now more viable and practically at the same feature level as CUDA based solution. Still, as of 2.79a, be aware that there are rough edges, bugs, and overall it is not as polished as NVidia hardware.

Besides that, GPU computing on OSX is not as performant as on other platforms. 
If you are serious about GPU acceleration consider other platforms like Linux or Windows.

Basically AMD HD 5### seris is no longer supported for Cycles rendering, as [stated in the Blender Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL)

Comment: cheers. I have ahtlon x2 and have ordered gtx750 card is this OK?

Comment: Cards [above compute capability 2.0 should be ok](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html) accoding to the manual, though as of next release 2.79 is purported to be the last supporting GTX 5## series cards.